# Additional tab, when editing table

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, tableview

There is an additional pane with buttons appears in messages app on iPhone when tapping Edit button. See link, screenshot.

[Messages app on iPhone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0EyR.png)

Is it a default `UITableView` property? (Probably not)

Is it a `UIView`, showing over tableView with delegate methods for handling buttons actions?

I searched everywhere with no luck. Can you give me the cue, how I can make the same one myself?
My app is written in Swift.

Comment: it's a view ......

Comment: read about UIToolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all, you were right, it is a `UIToolbar`, and it is quite easy to use.

To create toolbar:

```
let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: 50))
    toolbar.barStyle = UIBarStyle.default
    toolbar.items = [
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelAction)),
        UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil),
        UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.plain, target: self, action: #selector(nextAction))]
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
```

To show it:

```
view.addSubview(toolbar)
```

To remove it:

```
toolbar.removeFromSuperView
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a UIToolbar. Just add it at the bottom of your viewcontroller's view.